# Как сверстать блок из изображений разного размера

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сверстать подобный блок. Пытался, но получается неумелая фигня (возможно, из-за позабытого опыта в верстке) :)

```css
.gallery-block {
  height: 661px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-block"> <!-- Подобие блока. -->
  <div style="float: left; width: 100%; max-width: 517px;">
    <img style="height: 517px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 100%; max-width: 251px;">
    <img style="height: 177px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
    <img style="height: 177px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
    <img style="height: 177px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 100%; max-width: 241px;">
    <img style="height: 323px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
    <img style="height: 323px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать такое легко с помощью `flexbox`. Примерно так:

```css
.gallery-block {
  display: flex;
}
.gallery-block div {overflow:hidden;margin:4px}
.gallery-block div img {display:inline-block;margin:2px 0}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-block">
   <div style="width: 300px;height:351px;">
      <img style="height: 100%;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
   </div>
   <div style="width: 251px;">
      <img style="height: 111px;width:100%" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
      <img style="height: 111px;width:100%" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
     <img style="height: 111px;width:100%" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
   </div>
   <div style="width: 241px;">
      <img style="height: 171px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
      <img style="height: 171px;" src="http://s6.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/06/18/3/1434596941_632146314.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли! Немного по теме вопроса: может, вы могли бы посоветовать хорошую статью по `flexbox`?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, держите: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ :)

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!